# Logstash 6.2.1 Oracle JDBC plugin invalid character in query

Tags: oracle, jdbc, logstash

I'm trying to fetch data from an Oracle database using this query but I'm constantly getting an `Java::JavaSql::SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00911: invalid character` error:

```
statement => "select * from SYS.AUD$_ARCH where to_date('01-01-18', 'dd-MM-yy') > ntimestamp#;"
```

I tried escaping the table name but I still get the error (also the # in the column name and the >):

```
statement => "select * from SYS.AUD\$_ARCH where to_date('01-01-18', 'dd-MM-yy') > ntimestamp#;"
```

Using `statement_filepath` also raises the same error.

This is my locale output `locale`

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using a lowercase table name `sys.aud$_arch`.

`statement => "select * from sys.aud$_arch where to_date('01-01-18', 'dd-MM-yy') > ntimestamp#"`